# Send an email with attached file

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

I'm with a problem... When I try to open the Gmail from an Intent, with a attached file, It shows to me in a Toast: "cant send empty file". My PDF file is inside in a folder in my app (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/teste.com.br.cartaovisitateste/files/business.pdf), but I cant suck this file, to put in the email. Problably, the problem is with to localize the path, but I don't know how to solve this

This is my code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "wallacekingsdon@gmail.com");
//  it does not work
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/digitalsa.com.br.cartaovisitaultragaz/files/business.pdf"));
//  it does not work too
Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "business.pdf"));
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, String.valueOf(Hawk.get("registro_nome")).concat(" Business Card"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Enviando e-mail..."));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
```

The MIME type of a PDF file is `application/pdf`. The MIME type of an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` is either the type used for `EXTRA_STREAM` or `EXTRA_TEXT`. In your case, you are using `EXTRA_STREAM`, and that appears to be attempting to point to a PDF file.

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/digitalsa.com.br.cartaovisitaultragaz/files/business.pdf"));
```

Do not hardcode paths. And do not pass things that are not `Uri` values to `Uri.parse()`. A `Uri` has a scheme, like `https`, `file`, or `content`.

```
Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "business.pdf"));
```

First, you are not putting that in an extra. The value is not being used.

Second, `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+ in an `Intent` extra. You will get a `FileUriExposedException`. Use `FileProvider` to serve up the PDF, and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to put into `EXTRA_STREAM`, at least on Android 7.0+ devices.

Comment: Something like this?


`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.setType("application/pdf");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, String.valueOf(Hawk.get("registro_nome")).concat(" Business Card"));
Uri fp = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "teste.com.br.cartaovisitateste.provider", new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "business.pdf"));
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fp);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Sending e-mail...")); `

Comment: Because this /\ give me an error: **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/**

Comment: @WallaceBaldenebre: Your error is because you do not have your `FileProvider` metadata configured properly. See [the `FileProvider` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Comment: @WallaceBaldenebre: Also, your various bits of code have indicated many different places where this PDF file is. `"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/digitalsa.com.br.cartaovisitaultragaz/files/business.pdf"` is not the same as new `File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "business.pdf")`, which is not the same as `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePa‌​th(), "business.pdf")`. Figure out where this file is. Then figure out the code to provide you the correct Java `File` for the file.

Comment: Wow! I'm very close now... My Gmail gets the business.pdf, but when I try to send the email, it returns an error: "Could not send attachment". See the code that's almost working:

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("*/*");
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, String.valueOf(Hawk.get("registro_nome")).concat(" Business Card"));
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "teste.com.br.cartaovisitateste.provider", new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "business.pdf")));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Sending e-mail..."));`

Comment: my meta-data is:

`<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="digitalsa.com.br.cartaovisitaultragaz.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>`

Comment: @WallaceBaldenebre: Other than replacing `i.setType("*/*")` with `i.setType("application/pdf")`, I do not know what else may be going wrong.

Comment: I tried replace `("*/*")` with `("application/pdf")`, but nothing.. It returns the same error: **Could not send attachment** :(

Comment: Does the order of the intents influence something?

Comment: @WallaceBaldenebre: Usually, that is a permissions issue, but you seem OK there. Are you *sure* that your PDF is in the root of external storage? IOW, if you plug your device into your development machine, and you look at external storage (what your development machine might call "Internal storage"), your `business.pdf` file is right there in the root directory?  "Does the order of the intents influence something?" -- you only have one `Intent`.

Comment: No, It's in the Internal Storage. The path is:
`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/teste.com.br.cartaovisitateste/files/business.pdf`

Comment: I tried to use `getRootDirectory()` instead of `getExternalStorageDirectory()` , but the first option shows the error in the Logcat: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /system/business.pdf`

Comment: @WallaceBaldenebre: "The path is: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/teste.com.br.cartaovisitate‌​ste/files/business.p‌​df" -- then the `File` is `new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "business.pdf")`, and you need to use that consistently everywhere (in `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` and wherever you are doing the work to create this PDF file in the first place).

Comment: WOW MAN!!!! IT WORKED!!! FINALLY!!! THANKS, GRACIAS, OBRIGADO, спасибо!!!